# Left join same table with count specific value

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have one table where I would like to count the amount of names grouped by school, count whether school has one or two genders as well as count the specific occurence of a particular value in 3 different columns. I am able to do the counts in two different tables but I want to join them to make 1 table

| FName | School | Gender | Events | Events2 | Events3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ann | Marymount | F | HJ | LJ | TJ |
| Peter | Marymount | M | 100 | 200 | 400 |
| Drew | St Hughs | M | 100 | 200 |  |
| Davis | St Hughs | M | 200 |  |  |
| Kat | Campion | F | 400 |  |  |
| Molly | Campion | F | 400 |  |  |
| Mike | Marymount | M | 800 |  |  |
| Fran | Campion | M | 100 | 200 |  |

These are the 2 separate queries I use successfully and create two different result sets

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(FName) as cnt, COUNT(DISTINCT(Gender)) as gnd, school, COUNT(*) FROM entries WHERE school <> 'Unattached' GROUP BY school";
```

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(Events + Events2 + Events3) as events, school, COUNT(*) FROM entries WHERE (school <> 'Unattached') AND (Events = '100') OR (Events2 = '100') OR (Events3 = '100') GROUP BY school";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

I have tried using a union but it only gives me results for second query and the count of names is off.

```
$sql = "
SELECT COUNT(FName) as cnt, COUNT(Events + Events2 + Events3) as events, COUNT(DISTINCT(Gender)) as gnd, school 
FROM entries WHERE (school <> 'Unattached')
UNION
SELECT COUNT(FName) as cnt, COUNT(Events + Events2 + Events3) as events, COUNT(DISTINCT(Gender)) as gnd, school 
FROM entries WHERE (school <> 'Unattached') AND (Events = '100') OR (Events2 = '100') OR (Events3 = '100')
GROUP BY school";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

The left join gave me no results because I didn't know how to fit the 2 WHERE clauses.

How can I join the two queries to get one table with the following result

| School | # of Participants | # Genders | # 100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marymount | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| St Hughs | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Campion | 3 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: What is `COUNT(Events + Events + Events3)` supposed to count? `COUNT(<expression>)` counts the number of rows where the expression is not NULL.

Comment: Content relating to "Conditional Aggregation": [SQL GROUP BY and COUNT and conditional SUM with column value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72056614/2943403) and [GROUP BY with COUNT condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46728057/2943403) and [Conditional sum in Group By query MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16517298/2943403) and [MySQL query group by and count on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47873846/2943403) and [how to SUM a column by different condition then group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66133240/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUM()` to add up the number of rows where a condition is true. This works because a boolean value is `1` when it's true, `0` when it's false, so `SUM()` gets this count.

```
SELECT school, 
    COUNT(*) AS num_participants, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT gender) AS num_genders, 
    SUM(events = '100' OR events2 = '100' OR events3 = '100') AS num_100
FROM entries
WHERE school != 'Unattached'
GROUP BY school
```

Comment: Does it also work to use `SUM('100' IN (events, events2, events3))`?  I didn't test this, but I feel like I've done this before.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, that should work as well. I've used that in code before.